# TypeScript | Be able to get name of method which gets called

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to get the method callers name from within a method javascript.

Take the following example:

```
user() {
  return this.hasOne();
}
```

```
hasOne() {
  // Inside of here I want to be able to access the 'user' method name.
}
```

Is there a way to do it by utilising reflection or would I need to do the following way:

```
user() {
  return this.hasOne('user');
}
```

I wanted to just harness the method name to determine the parameter.

Comment: There is basically *never* a reason that you would need that. This is a design smell. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: So the idea is, this is a model which interacts with the API. The api has relationships so in this example is the model was a Post model, I would specify the user as a method and I'd be able to do something like `Post.first().user()` which would in turn construct the API uri and return the user but with the `hasOne` class methods. I just thought, to save duplication and ease of programming harnessing the user method name with an option to override would be a safe bet.

Comment: Or @JaredSmith would a safe option be to call the method but pass through the type. I.E: `public function user() { return this.hasOne(User) }`

Comment: Typically the way you want to represent a distinct set of enumerated states is with an enum. Have an enum of the states and simple named methods that call the logic method with different members of the enum. It's slightly more verbose but extremely clear/type-safe

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Can you share an example?

Comment: Posted as an answer, waaaay too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're after correctly, you want a method that has some logic that operates on different domain entities but you want convenience methods over top of it. In pseudo-Typescript:

```js
class Whatever {
    protected doesLogic(thing) {
        // business logic
    }

    public thing () {
        return this.doesLogic('thing');
    }

    public otherThing () {
        return this.doesLogic('otherThing');
    }
}
```

You are asking for a way to get the name of the calling public method to pass to the method that does the logic so you don't have to actually type out all the public convenience methods. There really isn't a good way to do that: in order for the class to be well-typed you'll need to spell out the methods, and once you do that it isn't any more typing to add the explicit parameter:

```js
class Whatever {
    protected doesLogic() {
        const caller = /* deep voodoo magic */
        // do stuff
    }
}

const w = new Whatever();
w.user(); // Error! method 'user' does not exist on type Whatever!
```

And once you write out the user method it isn't that big a deal to have it pass an explicit parameter with a string or whatever. There *used* to be a way [to accomplish this in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller), but it's been deprecated for a long, long time for being more trouble than it was worth, and it's certainly not going to work in Typescript.

Now that we've put that to bed, there are a couple of different ways to encode this nicely in Typescript. Let's start with an interface:

```js
interface ILikeThings {
    firstThing: () => number
    secondThing: () => number
}

class Foo implements ILikeThings {
    protected bizLogic(thing: keyof ILikeThings): number {
        // does some business logic
        return 5;
    }

    firstThing () {
        return this.bizLogic('firstThing');
    }

    secondThing () {
        return this.bizLogic('secondThing');
    }
}
```

This is type-safe, extensible, makes autocomplete work in an IDE, etc. Another way to represent it is to use an enum:

```js
enum Things {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
}

class Bar {
    protected bizLogic(thing: Things): number {
        // does some business logic
        return 5;
    }

    firstThing () {
        return this.bizLogic(Things.FIRST);
    }

    secondThing () {
        return this.bizLogic(Things.SECOND);
    }
}
```

Note that since `bizLogic` isn't part of the public API surface the two can overlap somewhat: `class Bar implements ILikeThings` still works just fine. As for why you'd want to use one or the other, the enum solution works better when you know all the possible things in advance and don't need extensibility:

```js
enum CardinalDirections {
   NORTH,
   SOUTH,
   EAST,
   WEST,
}
```

It's really nice to use (the `keyof ISomeInterface` thing is a bit weird), you can even add the enum members as static properties on the class for added convenience if users need access to the enum:

```js
class Bar {
    static FIRST = Things.FIRST
    static SECOND = Things.SECOND
...
}

// later
const bar = new Bar();
Bar.FIRST;
```

Unlike interfaces enums also still exist at runtime, usually as integers or strings. But you can't extend an enum. So I recommend the enum solution wherever possible, but pick which ever one works better for your case.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBlgGsIBUAWoA5gM7IDeAUMjcjMFCWAcQFzIAUAlMgLwB8yEAFcAtgCNo1WiQgIA9iAAmLEEXbc+gkRKkBfSpQQAbOCTIAxefOTBRAB2MRREcGQzY8hNWSq1k9lDykAiQSsjiwABe6PJEwAgcYN7qyDgAnvIwaJg4qqRc7DqSUBTS-jQA9JXISvIQZCTyLhHCJKANZMZxCeUVUBBgwlAgyACsANx9Bn30jMwpnDx+FTQDQyPIycAkAHSRMT2JAORzTPnHXFP+M-6yCsr5S2Wra4PDo9t7B7HxJ-eKFQpS7XWgGGauMTIfK+PoWVAAJQAyrgADR9JEAUQAwgB5AByABF0TMTGYyAAhOClFY0JhwMAJZDw5G4PjQlJ7Fkovr0xkIZBYvFE9kw3ZCgmEwz+QLBORhCLRX4JJIpdgwwpCMQlF6vaq1eqNZoocRtDrmZDdP59fzrD7jUE0W60M4LYjPWn9d6bL77JVHDhi7m4K7TaUyOSAp6aT2272fQjff1-QOc8U4yWhm6UAxAA)